# How to refactor the use of Parallel

Tags: c#, design-patterns, task-parallel-library

In our code base we have a lot ot methods which are basicly just plumbing and looks like this:

```
    public void Execute()
    {
        _performanceLogger.Log("Start");

        var chunks = GetChunksToWorkOn();

        Parallel.ForEach(chunks , chunk =>
        {
            using (var container = ObjectFactory.Container.GetNestedContainer())
            {
                using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
                {
                    container.GetInstance<Worker>().Execute(chunk);
                    unitOfWork.Commit();
                }
            }
        });

        _performanceLogger.Log("Done");
    }
```

I was thinking of creating a template method to replace these calls, something in the lines of:

```
public interface IProcessInParallel
{
    void Execute<T>(Func<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>> funcToRetrieveChunksOfWorkForEachParallelProcess) where T : IProcessInParallelTask;
}

public interface IProcessInParallelTask
{
    void DoWork(IEnumerable<object> objects);
}

public class ProcessInParallel : IProcessInParallel
{
    private readonly IPerformanceLogger _performanceLogger;

    public ProcessInParallel(IPerformanceLogger performanceLogger)
    {
        _performanceLogger = performanceLogger;
    }

    public void Execute<T>(Func<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>> funcToRetrieveChunksOfWorkForEachParallelProcess) where T : IProcessInParallelTask
    {
        _performanceLogger.Log("Start");

        var chunks = funcToRetrieveChunksOfWorkForEachParallelProcess.Invoke();

        Parallel.ForEach(chunks, chunk =>
        {
            using (var container = ObjectFactory.Container.GetNestedContainer())
            {
                using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
                {
                    container.GetInstance<T>().DoWork(chunk);
                    unitOfWork.Commit();
                }
            }
        });

        _performanceLogger.Log("Done");
    }
}
```

Only problem with this approach is that it uses object... which is ugly not safe and causes casts.

Im browsing my patterns book but havent found the right solution yet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is a good start. You can make this more light-weight by replacing inheritance with generics and delegates.

1. You change `T` to `TChunk` (more accurate naming)
2. The chunk factory should be of type `Func<TChunk>`
3. And you need a delegate that represents the work executed on a chunk: `Action<IContainer, container>`

```
public void Execute<TChunk>(var _performanceLogger, Func<TChunk> getChunks, Action<IContainer, container> doWork)
    {
        _performanceLogger.Log("Start");

        var chunks = getChunks();

        Parallel.ForEach(chunks, chunk =>
        {
            using (var container = ObjectFactory.Container.GetNestedContainer())
            {
                using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
                {
                    doWork(container, chunk);
                    unitOfWork.Commit();
                }
            }
        });

        _performanceLogger.Log("Done");
    }
}


Execute<IEnumerable<object>>(
    logger,
    () => GetChunksToWorkOn(),
    (container, chunk) => container.GetInstance<Worker>().DoWork(chunk));
```

Variantions to this are certainly possible. Note that we are not relying on inheritance. Interfaces are logically nothing more than function packs anyway.

By pulling `container.GetInstance<Worker>()` into the lambda we save one generic type parameter and make our helper method more lightweight. This is a trade-off that could also be done the other way.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an interface for your *chunk* object, and use it instead of `object`:

```
public interface IChunk
{
    // whatever
}

public interface IProcessInParallel
{
    void Execute<T>(Func<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IChunk>>> getChunks) where T : IProcessInParallelTask;
}
```

Then you can pass any method with signature like:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<RealChunk>> GetRealChunks()
{
    //...
}
```

where `RealChunk` is a class that implements `IChunk`. This is possible, [thanks to C# 4 variance feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).